# Magento: Shop by category filter is not showing up when flat categories are enabled

Tags: magento

For some reason, the "Shop by" category filter layered navigation disappears when I enable flat categories. I tried checking "Is Anchor", but it doesn't seem to make a difference. When the flat categories are disabled, the right category filters show up, regardless of the "Is Anchor" entry. I already tried reindexing the categories, category products, and product attributes, but still no luck. I am tracing the code, and so far, it seems that the getFilters() function called in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php returns empty consequently disabling the entire block. I appreciate any help on this matter. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you reindex after setting flat categories to true.
2. Check your flat category table either its empty or for some reason your code is not able to create a table specific to store ID.
3. Check var folder for logs and reports there you might find some exception etc logged by Magento.Make sure Log was set to on.
4. Clear your Cache.